# error: memory read failed for 0x0 Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I got this error while running a XCTestCase (iPhone 6s plus iOS 9.3) with the following code:

```
        let x = user as! ClientUser
        x.set(cpf: CPF(cpf: self.makeRandomCPF())!)
        let rg = self.requestId().id // this line was for debugging purposes
        let rgrg = RG(rg: "\(rg)") // this line was for debugging purposes
        let rgString = rgrg!.toString() // this line was for debugging purposes
        let id = x.id.id // this line was for debugging purposes
        x.set(cpf: nil) // this line was for debugging purposes
        x.set(rg: nil) // this is the line where the error occurs
```

the class ClientUser is defined as:

```
public class ClientUser: User {

// MARK: -Methods
public func set(cpf cpf: CPF?) -> Future<Bool, NSError> {
    let promise = Promise<Bool, NSError>()

    if let cpf = cpf {
        UserFactory.singleton.exists(cpf: cpf)
            .onSuccess(callback: { exists in
                if exists {
                    promise.failure(AlreadyExistsException(domain: "User.ClientUser.set(cpf:)", code: 0, userInfo: ["error": "AlreadyExistsException"]))
                }
                else {
                    self.cpf = cpf
                    promise.success(true)
                }
            })
            .onFailure(callback: { error in
                promise.failure(error)
            })
    }
    else {
        self.cpf = nil
        promise.success(true)
    }

    return promise.future
}

public func set(rg rg: RG?) -> Future<Bool, NSError> {
    let promise = Promise<Bool, NSError>()

    if let rg = rg {
        UserFactory.singleton.exists(rg: rg)
            .onSuccess(callback: { exists in
                if exists {
                    promise.failure(AlreadyExistsException(domain: "User.ClientUser.set(rg:)", code: 0, userInfo: ["error":"AlreadyExistsException"]))
                }
                else {
                    self.rg = rg
                    promise.success(true)
                }
            })
            .onFailure(callback: { error in
                promise.failure(error)
            })
    }
    else {
        self.rg = nil
        promise.success(true)
    }

    return promise.future
}

override class public var className: String {
    return "ClientUser"
}
```

}

Everything looks just fine, the method set(cpf:) is called just as expected but the set(rg:) results on that error.

Don't know what to do, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The Swift compiler seems to slip up every now and then, especially if your code makes use of generics. I had this crash consistently on a random line of code, using Xcode 8.3.3. Cleaning and building fixed it for me.